# Fractional max-pooling in keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras

The existing function in keras lib including max-pooling, average pooling, etc.

However, I would like to implement fractional max-pooling in keras based on the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6071.

My implementation are as follow:

```
model = Sequential()
......
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
```

So, instead of model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))), I would like to implement something like the following:

```
model.add(fractionalMaxpool2D(..............))
```

Is it possible?
I am currently using keras as backend in tensorflow.

Appreciate if someone would provide the algorithm/code.

I am quite new to this as I didn't wrote any custom layer before so could anyone kindly help out? Thanks!

Comment: You need to be more specific. Do you want people to implement the algorithm for you?

Comment: Yes! That would be nice. Alright I will edit the post to be more specific! thanks

Comment: your questions is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991470/using-tensorflow-layers-in-keras).

Comment: Not ideal, but you can alternate between upscale and downscale to effectively get 2/3 and 3/2.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can do that by implementing your custom layer

```
class FractionalMaxpool2D(Layer):
    def __init__(self, output_dim):
        super(FractionalMaxpool2D, self).__init__()
        self.output_dim = output_dim
    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
        # This kind of layer doesn't have any variable
        pass
    def call(self, x):
        # Handle you algorithm here
        return ....  
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        # return the output shape
        return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)
```

The problem is it's difficult to implement the core function for the Fractional max pooling that uses GPU.
Please check [this discussion](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/829) from Keras's Github.

Comment: Alright thank for the advice! As i am new to it, would you kindly explain what's going on with the code? thanks

Comment: I means that you should create the custom layer for your purpose. The custom layer is extended from Layer class. Some important method in your layer is:
- build: create the trainable variables if it is needed.
- call: perform your calculation to get the output
- compute_output_shape: return the output shape (what is the shape of data after it goes through your layer)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Keras Lambda Layer to Wrap tf.nn.fractional_max_pool, like

FMP = Lambda(lambda img, pool_size: tf.nn.fractional_max_pool(img, pool_size))

Now You can Use FMP in your Keras Code like other layers with Two Arguments

1. Img: with dimensions like [batch, height, width, channels]
2. pool_size: [1.0, pool_size_you_want, pool_size_you_want, 1.0]

The first and last are 1.0, which is because tf doesnot perform pooling on batch_size and channels, it performs on height and width