# Using Tensorflow Layers in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I've been trying to build a sequential model in Keras using the pooling layer `tf.nn.fractional_max_pool`. I know I could try making my own custom layer in Keras, but I'm trying to see if I can use the layer already in Tensorflow. For the following code snippet:

```
p_ratio=[1.0, 1.44, 1.44, 1.0]

model = Sequential()
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((2,2), input_shape=(1, 48, 48)))
model.add(Conv2D(320, (3, 3), activation=PReLU()))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(320, (3, 3), activation=PReLU()))
model.add(InputLayer(input_tensor=tf.nn.fractional_max_pool(model.layers[3].output, p_ratio)))
```

I get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEziD.png). I've tried some other things with `Input` instead of `InputLayer` and also the Keras Functional API but so far no luck.

Comment: Good job. I suggest moving the EDIT part in an answer (there is nothing wrong in answering your own questions in SO) and accept it.

Comment: @desertnaut will do!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Got it to work. For future reference, this is how you would need to implement it. Since tf.nn.fractional_max_pool returns 3 tensors, you need to get the first one only:

```
model.add(InputLayer(input_tensor=tf.nn.fractional_max_pool(model.layers[3].output, p_ratio)[0]))
```

Or using Lambda layer:

```
def frac_max_pool(x):
    return tf.nn.fractional_max_pool(x,p_ratio)[0]
```

With the model implementation being:

```
model.add(Lambda(frac_max_pool))
```

Comment: do you know a way of doing this with the functional API?