# Tensorflow layer in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

How can we use a layer from `tf.contrib.layers` in keras ?

I tried to mix the tf layer inside my other keras layers.

```python
input = Input(shape=state_shape)
conv = Conv2D(64, (6, 6), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu')(input)
spatial_softmax = tf.contrib.layers.spatial_softmax(conv, name='spatial_softmax', data_format='NHWC')
fc = Dense(128, activation='relu')(spatial_softmax)
fc = Dense(128, activation='relu')(fc)
output = Dense(action_size, activation='softmax')(fc)

Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
```

But when I run the code I get the following error

```python
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Edit: It's not the same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991470/using-tensorflow-layers-in-keras), I am asking for a layer with trainable weights and not a deterministic layer. Do the gradients will backprop to the layer ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to put that inside a Lambda layer:

```
spatial_softmax = Lambda(lambda x: spatial_softmax(x, name='spatial_softmax',
                         data_format='NHWC'))(conv)
```

Comment: As the temperature is a learnable Variable inside the spatial_softmax layer, will it work with a Lambda ?

Comment: @Wisym Which temperature are you talking about?

Comment: It is a variable inside the spatial_softmax https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/spatial_softmax
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.6/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py#L2754